# Is it possible to capture/redirect the standard output of a process that I did not launch, in .net?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, process, .net-2.0, pinvoke

If I know the process identifier, is there some mechanism in .net (or pinvoke as last resort) to capture/redirect the standard output of a process that I did not launch?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/429225/capture-output-from-unrelated-process)?

Answer (score 1):

You could [AttachConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952(v=vs.85).aspx) your process to the console of the other process, and then use the usual console I/O functions to read and write from it.

Remember to use [FreeConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683150(v=vs.85).aspx) to detach from the process' current console first.

Comment: @CesarGon - I gave it a whirl but AttachConsole returned false (marshaled from 0)

Comment: @SFun28: Try `GetLastError` to find out why it failed.

Comment: @CesarGon - it returns 5.  Per the pinvoke site, I'm using Marshal.GetLastWin32Error to get that number.

Comment: @SFun28 It's an 'Access is denied' error. If you use `GetLastError`, you can see error codes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx). See [this link](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.attachconsole) for more information on the error.

Comment: @Centro - thanks for the links.  I followed the code-sample but doesn't work for me.  I think I'll look for another approach.

Comment: @SFun28: If you read the documentation page for AttachConsole, you'll see that error 5 (access denied) is returned if the process is already attached to a console. You need to detach from the current console first through FreeConsole (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683150(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @SFun28 From MSDN: _" If the calling process is already attached to a console, the error code returned is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (5)."_ So your calling process is already attached to a console. Try first call [FreeConsole Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683150(v=vs.85).aspx) and `AttachConsole` after that.

Comment: @Centro/CesarGon - one step further.  Called FreeConsole and now I can call AttachConsole with no error.  Unfortunately the output of the process whose console I'm attaching is not appearing in standard output of the running process.  maybe its a .net thing (the calling process is .net, not the process I'm trying to attach to)?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do this in .NET, you can redirect outputs for processes you start only via [ProcessStartInfo Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx).

Also as far as I know you cannot redirect I/O externally at all after a process has started, only the process itself can do it.

You can attach the calling process to the console of the specified process via [AttachConsole Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I've tried AttachedConsole, but doesn't seem to work.  please see the thread under @CesarGon's answer.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Looks like it indeed does not work, as is being pointed out by another answer in this thread.

I have not personally tried it, but it seems, since the answer was accepted, that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/429225/capture-output-from-unrelated-process) works.

Comment: another answer in that post points out that the solution does not work

Comment: @SFun28 - Thanks for pointing this out. I should have read the whole thread first (I figured that the accepted answer looked suspiciously simple ;-)